Is there a way of running Projected Gradient Descent (i.e. GD with hard constraints on the objective domain) with Julia's Optim package?
I'm trying to experiment with Projected Gradient Descent on some objective functions constrained by a hypercube. "Projected" here simply means that if the next steps falls outside the constraints, it is projected back onto the domain using Euclidian norm (the closest point that belongs to the domain). Unfortunately, as far as I can understand from reading this part of the Optim's documentation only soft constraints seem to be available. I'm just wondering if there might be some different roundabout way of using hard constraints (could it be setting outer_iterationsto 0 in Optim.Options)  - or am I missing something/misunderstanding the documentation?

Dunno about Julia, but anyway my advice is to cast the net a bit wider -- there are many optimization algorithms implemented in other languages. I know for sure there is L-BFGS-B in Fortran originally and maybe with interfaces or translations in other languages; doubtless there are many more. If you must use Julia, you can use an unconstrainted solver repeatedly: find the n-dimensional unconstrained solution; find the (n - 1)-d unconstrained solution in each face plane; likewise (n - 2)-d, ..., 0-d (vertices).

If any k-d solution, with k > 0, falls within the constraints, you're done, otherwise the optimum is on one of the vertices. I know that's more than a little bookkeeping but anyway it's a way to get to a constrained solution using an unconstrained algorithm as building block.

Thanks @RobertDodier. Unfortunately I need to use GD and Julia. I might however simply follow you suggestion if I don't come up with something else that would work for many dimensions.

https://github.com/JuDO-dev/Progradio.jl is a projected gradient descent implementation in Julia
